# Convert list of strings to list of integers?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that I want to convert to a simple integer array.

Example:

```
my_list = ['This is a string', 'This is a string', 'Hi! I am a string', 'I dislike strings', 'This is a string', 'Not a number']
```

Converted to:

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3]
```

Elements in `my_list` that have the same value will all end up with the same integer in the converted array.

The idea behind this is that I want to utilize the following syntax (from matplotlib) to make a scatter chart, and it doesn't seem to like it when `y_train` or `i` is a string:

```
X_train_small_pca[y_train == i, 0]
```

How can I convert my list into integers, as above?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: `[int(x[1:]) - 1 for x in my_list]` that's it.

Comment: @vaultah, My examples were poor. I've updated my examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
>>> my_list = ['This is a string', 'This is a string', 'Hi! I am a string', 'I 
>>> dislike strings', 'This is a string', 'Not a number']
>>> mappedDict = dict(zip(set(my_list), xrange(len(my_list))))
>>> output = map(lambda x: mappedDict[x], my_list)
>>> output
[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3]
```

Explaining: You first remove duplicates in the list and map them with a single id (`int` in this case) into a dict. After that is as easy as transform each value in the list into the mapped id.

Comment: Oh, that's where he got those numbers. Index to the first occurence in original list of strings. +1

Answer (score 2):

Your issue: convert a list of strings into a list of integers, where the same strings should become the same integers (whatever those integer are)

The method `index("value")` of a list returns the first index where "value" is found. For all the identical strings "value" in the list, this method will return the same integer.

```
>>> my_list = ['This is a string', 'This is a string', 'Hi! I am a string', 'I dislike strings', 'This is a string', 'Not a number']

>>> my_list.index('This is a string')
0

>>> indexes=[my_list.index(l) for l in my_list]
>>> print(indexes)
[0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['This is a string', 'This is a string', 'Hi! I am a string', 'I dislike strings', 'This is a string', 'Not a number']

converter = {}
i = 1

for item in my_list:
    if item not in converter:
        converter[item] = i
        i += 1

int_list = [converter[i] for i in my_list]
```

Comment: Any reason to use `converter.get` instead of `if item not in converter` ? The second one seems easier to understand.

Comment: Nope, not at all. I agree that your change makes it easier to understand. Gonna make a change in the code

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a list by applying a function to all members of another list.
This is a list comprehension.

```
l1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
l2 = [int(x) for x in l1]
print l2
```

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Of course, you have some completely different function in mind, and I have no idea how you got those numbers from those strings, but I  assume it is irrelevant.  List comprehension will use whatever function you want.

```
l1 = ['string', 'this', 'is']
def f(s):
    return len(s)
l2 = [f(x) for x in l1]
print l2
```

[6, 4, 2]