# Replacing and Storing

Tags: python, replace, store, file-handling

**So, here is what I got:**

```
def getSentence():

  sentence = input("What is your sentence? ").upper()

  if sentence == "":
    print("You haven't entered a sentence. Please re-enter a sentence.")
    getSentence()
  elif sentence.isdigit():
    print("You have entered numbers. Please re-enter a sentence.")
    getSentence()
  else:
    import string
    for c in string.punctuation:
      sentence = sentence.replace(c,"")
      return sentence

def list(sentence):

  words = []
  for word in sentence.split():
    if not word in words:
      words.append(word)
    print(words)

def replace(words,sentence):
  position = []
  for word in sentence:
    if word == words[word]:
      position.append(i+1)
      print(position)

sentence = getSentence()
list = list(sentence)
replace = replace(words,sentence)
```

I have only managed to get this far, my full intention is to take the sentence, seperate into words, change each word into a number e.g.

```
words = ["Hello","world","world","said","hello"]
```

And make it so that each word has a number:

So lets say that "hello" has the value of 1, the sentence would be '1 world world said 1'

And if world was 2, it would be '1 2 2 said 1'
Finally, if "said" was 3, it would be '1 2 2 1 2'

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I will then develop this code so that the sentence and such is stored into a file using `file.write()` and `file.read()` etc

**Thanks**

Comment: You don't say what the problem is that you are having. What is the problem?

Comment: There is "world" twice in your `words` list, but in the code you're trying to avoid that, right? Should the assignment from words to numbers be automatic? What exactly is the replace function going to do?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919672/convert-list-of-strings-to-list-of-integers) is nearly the same question asked earlier today. Also shouldn't it be `1 2 2 3 1`?

Comment: lol, sorry yeah typo

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter what order the words are turned into numbers? Is `Hello` and `hello` two words or one? Why not something like:

```
import string

sentence = input()  # user input here
sentence.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
# strip out punctuation

replacements = {ch: str(idx) for idx, ch in enumerate(set(sentence.split()))}
# builds {"hello": 0, "world": 1, "said": 2} or etc

result = ' '.join(replacements.get(word, word) for word in sentence.split())
# join back with the replacements
```

Comment: Thanks, but the part where you are stripping out punctuation gives me this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "C:/Python33/j.py", line 4, in <module>`
    `sentence.translate(str.maketrans(None, None, string.punctuation))`
`TypeError: must be str, not None`

Comment: @OllieMills ah yes, it needs empty strings not `None`s. My mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, so that works perfectly. I have a rough idea of how to but I need the program to remember those values. e.g if the user inputted the values:

"Hello world world said hello"

The program would store them as 2 1 1 0 2

If I wanted to recall them, I could input 2 1 1 0 2 and the program would give out "Hello world world said hello"

I don't want to sound as if I am getting you to do it all for me but I need to put the values into a file and read from a file; this is kinda out of my reach :)

Comment: @OllieMills You should look into using `pickle` to store your replacement dictionary, then. It's worthy of another question if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the position in which each word is you can do

```
positions = map(words.index,words)
```

Also, NEVER use built-in function names for your variables or functions. And also never call your variables the same as your functions (`replace = replace(...)`), functions are objects

Edit: In python 3 you must convert the iterator that map returns to a list

```
positions = list(map(words.index, words))
```

Or use a comprehension list

```
positions = [words.index(w) for w in words]
```

Comment: ick that's kind of slow. If you're already building a sequence of unique words, just do `enumerate(words)`. If you're throwing away the letters then `next(zip(*enumerate(words))` works

Comment: This doesn't need to be a unique sequence... So it's the same as building a unique sequence and then using enumerate

Comment: Right,  but it's also O(n^2). `str.index` is notoriously slow. I wouldn't use this on any string longer than a hundred words or so.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea (although don't think it's better than the rest), use dictionaries:

```
dictionary = dict()
for word in words:
    if word not in dictionary:
        dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)+1
```

Also, on your code, when you're calling "getSentence" inside "getSentence", you should return its return value:

```
if sentence == "":
    print("You haven't entered a sentence. Please re-enter a sentence.")
    return getSentence()
elif sentence.isdigit():
    print("You have entered numbers. Please re-enter a sentence.")
    return getSentence()
else:
    ...
```

Comment: You shouldn't reprompt for user input this way. It's creating a recursive function when you really don't need one. Use an infinite loop (`while True`) and do your validation at the end. `break` if the input is valid.

Comment: @Adam, you're right, one should just validate the input and ask again for a correct answer.
I just saw that he was calling again the getSentence function without a return, so I commented on that.
Anyway, in this case, where the recursion will just happen a couple of times at most (well, how many times can a user enter a wrong input?) it shouldn't be a problem, but I agree that it's unnecessary and could be a problem in other cases.

Another reason I posted this was because I thought that Python had tail call recursion, I now realize it doesn't (without workarounds), so thanks for that.